# Can I use Remote Notification for messaging app to wake up my application since I can not use push kit

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushkit, remote-notifications, silent-notification

I have a messaging app, in the past I was using push-kit to wake up my app in order to download message in background or when app killed.

As Pushkit I can not use any more, so I must use remote notification, but if I add in the payload of remote notification content-type =1 and doesn’t add any badge or alert Apple called this as a silent notification so according to them, if app receive more than 5 silent push in hour they can throttle the notification.

My question is, if add badge and alert and content-type =1 in payload in order to wake up my app and download the message, can app receive more than 5 notification in hour and Apple will not throttle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer here maybe it can help someone else.

As i asked from apple, they says that if you add

> content-type =1

in remote notification, it looks like background notification for them or silent notification what ever you call... there is a limit of 3 silent notification per hour and also not guaranteed the delivery...
Note: In debug there is no limitation, if you want to test it, you should test it from testflight.